# How a virus injects itself to another machine's file?

Tags: malware, virus

Everyone says a computer virus replicates/attaches itself to another host file. This concept is not clear to me. I have read many articles but unable to understand how.

Say, virus V1 is the original virus. It has a payload saying "Hello World".
Two machines (M1 and M2) are available, each with 3 files.
At first, V1 is present on M1. It inserts payload within other 3 files. It can do so because the payload code is written within the virus V1. When files at M1 is executed, they display "Hello World".

How these infected files at M1 can infect files of M2?

How a virus can contain its own code (entire code) within itself?

It will be easy for me if anyone can address my question with an example or pseudo-code.

Comment: You have described two ***very*** different things. You have asked how it infects other files in the same machine, *then* asked how it travels by itself to another machine. You cannot confuse these things. What do you want to know?

Comment: "How a virus can contain its own code (entire code) within itself?" - I'm not sure how this is confusing or maybe I'm missing what you are asking. It's code. It can be copied. It can also be compressed and duplicated within the virus code.

Comment: specifically "how it travels by itself to another machine".

Comment: Ok, then we need to completely re-write your question to ask that.

Comment: Do you mean infecting files shared by M2? Like on a file share or shared drive, or are you excluding that scenario?

Comment: yes. But also consider in this way : I am executing one INFECTED file from M1, at M2.

Comment: I asked A or B, and you answered "yes". Yes what? Also, you do not execute a file at another machine.

Comment: I understand how it infects when machines are shared acccross network. But I do not understand this : if I execute one infected file at M2 then files of M2 must be infected. how?

Comment: Now you've completely changed the question again. Do you want to know how a virus on a computer infects other files ***on that computer*** or how it travels to other computers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103024/discussion-between-shamindra-parui-and-schroeder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been confusing and combining many different concepts into one. To understand how all this works, you need to separate out all the functions separately. Each is simple by itself.

Once the virus code is running, it can do what any other program can do on a computer. It can even trigger functions that already exist on the computer and other programs.

So, given this idea, it is trivial for the virus to scan the network for other machines and look for machines with vulnerabilities to exploit. Once it finds one, it can exploit that vulnerability and run the payload directly on the other machine. This is how wannacry worked, for example. Alternatively, it can look for shared drives and simply copy itself over to another machine. It's not running yet, but is waiting to be executed and then the cycle repeats.

So, it's not that the infected *file* reaches out to other *files*. It's a *program* that is seeking to exploit other *machines*. The fact that the program was hidden in another file does not factor in at all.